# Extract Text From Pandas DataFrame Based On Filters of a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df. In one column is "State" and in another column is "Text". I want to make a new column called "my_new_col" that extracts the word "Lime" from the "Text" column, only when the State Column = "Idaho"

```
df = {'State': ["Idaho", "Washington","Oregon","Idaho","Oregon"], 'Text': ["Lime Light","New Egg","Lime Inc","Monteray","NovaDing"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

Output:

```
    State       Text
0   Idaho       Lime Light
1   Washington  New Egg
2   Oregon      Lime Inc
3   Idaho       Monteray
4   Oregon      NovaDing
```

How do I get a dataframe that shows the following

```
    State       Text          my_new_col
0   Idaho       Lime Light    Lime
1   Washington  New Egg       None
2   Oregon      Lime Inc      None
3   Idaho       Monteray      None
4   Oregon      NovaDing      None
```

Another example could be to pull out text that matches regex into a new column

```
df = {'State': ["Idaho", "Washington","Oregon","Idaho","Oregon"], 'Text': ["1,234 Light","New Egg","Lime Inc","1223 Ring","NovaDing"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

Output:

```
    State       Text
0   Idaho       1,234 Light
1   Washington  New Egg
2   Oregon      Lime Inc
3   Idaho       1223 Ring
4   Oregon      NovaDing
```

How do I get a dataframe that shows the following. The regex would be \d,\d\d\d

```
    State       Text          my_new_col
0   Idaho       1,234 Light   1,234
1   Washington  New Egg       None
2   Oregon      Lime Inc      None
3   Idaho       1223 Ring     None
4   Oregon      NovaDing      None
```

Comment: Extracts the word 'lime'? Do you mean makes `my_new_col` equal to "lime" if the State is "Idaho" and the Text contains "Lime"?  Case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's case-sensitive:

```
df['my_new_col'] = None
df.loc[(df['State']=='Idaho') & (df['Text'].str.contains("Lime")), 'my_new_col'] = 'Lime'
print(df)
        State        Text my_new_col
0       Idaho  Lime Light       Lime
1  Washington     New Egg       None
2      Oregon    Lime Inc       None
3       Idaho    Monteray       None
4      Oregon    NovaDing       None
```

If case-insensitive:

```
df.loc[(df['State']=='Idaho') & (df['Text'].str.contains("Lime", case=False)), 'my_new_col'] = 'Lime'
```

...based on the update to the question, from the second example dataframe:

```
df.loc[(df['State']=='Idaho'), 'my_new_col'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\d,\d\d\d)")[0]
```

That puts `NaN` values in the column instead of `None`. If that matters:

```
df['my_new_col'] = None
df.loc[(df['State']=='Idaho'), 'my_new_col'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\d,\d\d\d)")[0] 
df.loc[df['my_new_col'].isnull(), 'my_new_col'] = None
```

Comment: I see how that could work. What if you want to extract based off of regex?

Comment: The [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) accessor allows for that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, how would you get it added to the new column?

Comment: Can you update the question with a specific example of what you're looking for? I'm not sure what you mean by "extract" in this case.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I was close, but didn't know I needed the [0] on the end.